# Unable to move folders in mounted NAS

Tags: gui, 20.10, filemanager, file-sharing

I have a NAS that I mounted using the GUI.

When I create a folder and then try to move it to another folder I get this error message:

```
there was an error moving the file into smb://server/folder/old no such file or directory
AME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.10"
VERSION_ID="20.10"
```

What is the cause for this problem?

Comment: Does your account on the Samba share allow you to create new directories?

Comment: yes, i can create new folder, but when i tried rename or move those folder then show this message: there was an error moving the file into smb://server/folder/old no such file or directory

Comment: hi everybody, can you help me about this issue